# Alinhar elementos com css dentro de uma div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Preciso fazer um elemento que tenha dentro dele vários cartões(outros elementos) e eu preciso que eles ocupem todo o espaço disponível e caso ultrapasse esse espaço ele deve quebrar a linha. Algumas observações:

[image: Imagem do problema]

Esse é o resultado que eu preciso ter, os cards(em cinza) tem um tamanho fixo(isso infelizmente não pode mudar no projeto) e precisam estar alinhados ao header a cima, para chegar nesse resultado eu utilizei o seguinte código:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  
}

header {
  width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 8rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <header>Header </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Qual o problema dele então?
[image: problema]

Quando existem poucos cards o `justify-content: space-between;` faz com que ele fique com esses espaçamentos entre eles.
Existe algum modo de deixar os cards responsivos e alinhados e caso tenham poucos cards eles fiquem alinhados no começo?

[image: Ideal]

Essa seria a situação ideal removendo o `justify-content: space-between;` mas sem o `justify-content: space-between;` quando o card não cabe mais no elemento ele faz essa quebra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão seria usar o [sistema de grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) do CSS, pois acho que com flexbox você não irá conseguir fazer isso.

Irá ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí é só definir *breakpoints* através de [@media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) para reduzir o número de cards por linha.

As classes `.conteudo` e `.card` teriam basicamente a estrutura:

```
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    gap: 10px; /* espaço entre os cards */
}

.card {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

No exemplo acima, serão exibidos 5 *cards* por linha (o número `5` na função `repeat`).

E um exemplo de uma *@media rule* onde seriam exibidos 4 cards por linha se a largura do *viewport* for de até 1280 pixels:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px){
    .content {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
}
```

Aí é só criar regras como desejar.

Veja funcionando:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  
}

header {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 10px; /* espaço entre os cards */
}

.card {
    background-color: gray;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1280px){
    .content {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .content {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .content {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 428px){
    .content {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <header>Header </header>
 <div class="content">
   <div class="card">1</div> 
   <div class="card">2</div> 
   <div class="card">3</div> 
   <div class="card">4</div> 
   <div class="card">5</div> 
   <div class="card">6</div> 
   <div class="card">7</div> 
   <div class="card">8</div> 
   <div class="card">9</div> 
   <div class="card">10</div> 
   <div class="card">11</div> 
   <div class="card">12</div> 
   <div class="card">13</div> 
   <div class="card">14</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Repare também que no `header` não foi preciso fazer aquela gambi que tinha no `width`, podendo ser omitido pois o `header` já é 100% de padrão, pois é um elemento de bloco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em `grid-template-columns: repeat()`, as opções `auto-fill` e `auto-fit` dispensam o uso de media queries, v.g. `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 8rem);`.

Comment: Olá @VanderSantos. Testei com os valores que vc sugeriu e não tive o resultado desejado. Fica um espaço sobrando na direita.

Comment: Sam, se você se refere ao espaço que fica quando há somente uma coluna, esse era o comportamento esperado considerando o `space-between` e o tamanho fixo dos cards - de todo o modo, nesse cenário, independente do valor de `justify-content`, ficaria sobrando espaço de algum lado. Por outro lado, com mais de uma coluna, não é normal que sobre espaço. Nesse sentido, confira: https://vanderms.github.io/frontend-how-to/grid-auto-fill/index.html

Comment: Interessante, mas fica ruim o alinhamento com tamanho fixo dos cards e o `space-between`, pq o espaço entre eles, em momentos, fica enorme, além do espaço sobrando quando fica apenas 1 coluna. Outro problema que vi foi o `margin-right` que vc usou, isso faz com que a margem dos cards mais à direita ultrapassem a área da div `.content`. Mas valeu pelo aprendizado.

Comment: Ops... O `margin-right` estava no original do autor da pergunta. Eu havia retirado, mas recoloquei para testar se era ele que estava produzindo o espaço que você mencionou. Depois, eu esqueci de retirar. De qualquer forma, tanto o margin-right quanto o margin-top só atrapalham já que a distância mínima entre os cards pode ser controlada pela propriedade `gap` do grid.

Comment: Pessoal eu consegui resolver com o 
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(11rem, 2fr));`

Answer (score 0):

Eu concordo com o @sam, ou seja, que o grid display é a melhor opção para fazer aquilo que pretende. Porém, se quiser mesmo utilizar flex display, existe um workaround que, basicamente, consiste em adicionar elementos apenas para efeitos de "enchimento" que depois torná-los invisíveis com css.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  
}

header {
  width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 8rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.card--dummy {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <header>Header </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card"></div> 
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
      <div class="card card--dummy"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```